# No solutions to Neumann problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$  be a bounded region in two or three dimensions with boundary $\partial  \Omega$  and D a
function such that $D(x) > 0$ for all $x ∈ \Omega $. Show that there are no solutions to the Neumann problem
$$
∇ · (D(x)∇c(x)) = \delta (x − x_0)   \         \  \  \  \  \  \  x, x_0 ∈ \Omega
$$
$$ 
∇c(x) · n = 0, x ∈ \partial \Omega .
$$

Could you outline an approach towards the question? Additional theory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, according to [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Product_rules) for divergence $\,\nabla\cdot \big(\,f\,\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}\,\big) = f\,\nabla\cdot\vec{\boldsymbol{v}} +\vec{\boldsymbol{v}}\cdot\nabla f\,$ we rewrite equation as

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
D\,\nabla^2c + \overrightarrow{\nabla c }\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla D} = \delta \left(x-x_0\right), & x\in\Omega\\
\overrightarrow{\nabla c} \cdot \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{n}} = 0, & x \in \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where I assume $\,\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{n}}\,$ is a normal vector of $\,\partial \Omega$.
Second, by [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green.27s_first_identity) we have

\begin{align}
\int_\Omega \Big(D\,\nabla^2c + \overrightarrow{\nabla c }\cdot \overrightarrow{\nabla D} \Big) \,dV = 
\oint_{\partial \Omega} \Big(\vec{\nabla c} \cdot \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{n}} \Big)\,D\,dS = 0
\end{align}
according to your boundary conditions.
But integral of [delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions) equals to $1$, so we conclude that the equation is inconsistent with given boundary conditions.